# How can I play sound on rspec success/failure when using guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

I had it configured once with autotest, but lately I'm using guard-rspec to run my specs in the background. I do have growl notifications but this requires reading the actual notification text which is a distraction during a fast red-green cycle. I would prefer a sound notification for success and failure, but I can't find any ready-to-use example of such a setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also haven't seen a such example setup, so you need to implement a [Notifier](http://rubydoc.info/gems/guard/Guard/Notifier):

```
module Guard::Notifier::Sound
  extend self

  def available?(silent = false, options = {})
    true
  end

  def notify(type, title, message, image, options = { })
    puts 'Play sound: ', type
  end
end
```

You can place this code directly into your `Guardfile`, register and make use of it with the following code:

```
Guard::Notifier::NOTIFIERS << [[:sound, ::Guard::Notifier::Sound]]
notification :sound
```

Of course you need to implement the actual sound playing. A simple implementation would be to fork to an external player like:

```
def notify(type, title, message, image, options = { })
  fork{ exec 'mpg123','-q',"spec/support/sound/#{ type }.mp3" }
end
```

### Update

With Spork the above direct inclusion into the `Guardfile` will not work, because Spork runs in a separate process and will not evaluate it. You need to create a supporting file, e.g. `spec/support/sound_notifier.rb` with a content like this:

```
module Guard::Notifier::Sound
  extend self

  def available?(silent = false, options = {})
    true
  end

  def notify(type, title, message, image, options = { })
    fork{ exec 'mpg123','-q',"spec/support/sound/#{ type }.mp3" }
  end
end

Guard::Notifier::NOTIFIERS << [[:sound, ::Guard::Notifier::Sound]]
```

and having just

```
require 'spec/support/sound_notifier'
notification :sound
```

in the `Guardfile`. Next you need to load the `sound_notifier` also in the Spork process. Since I do not use Spork I cannot verify it, but when I remember correctly happens in the `spec_helper.rb`:

```
Spork.prefork do
  require 'spec/support/sound_notifier'
end
```

Comment: it seems to get notifications about starting spork etc, but for some reason it doesn't get any notifications about actually running rspecs.

Comment: tried to debug it. it seems that when it runs rspecs NOTIFIERS doesn't contain the :sound notifier. it might be related to spork. may be Guardfile is not loaded. need to investigate a bit more

Comment: Sadly it will not work with Spork in this way, because Spork runs in another process and will not evaluate the `Guardfile` and thus have no `:sound` notifier as you've found out. I'll update my answer...